# Overriding serialization method of inbuilt types

Tags: protobuf-net

I need to switch different methods of serialization for some inbuilt types (DateTime for example) during runtime or at least during model initialization. What is the best approach to do this?
I have tried surrogating them with custom model (`RuntimeTypeModel.Add(typeof(DateTime), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(uint))`  ), but got error "Data of this type has inbuilt behaviour, and cannot be added to a model".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a scenario I have considered hugely, to be honest. For most of the "inbuilt behaviour" types it would be a really really bad idea to change the implementation, since it is part of the protobuf specifical; however, in the case of `DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, `Decimal` and `Guid` there are perhaps alternative layouts that could be supported. Can I ask what exactly it is that you want to do here? as there may be better ways to do it. Equally important would be: what is the magnitude? if it is just a few cases, then a shim property might be preferable, for example:

```
public DateTime When {get;set;}
[ProtoMember(4)]
private uint WhenSerialized {
   get { return YourConverter.FromDateTime(When); }
   set { When = YourConverter.ToDateTime(value); }
}
```

It may also possible to enable the "surrogate" handling for these types, but you can't use a surrogate to get directly to a `uint` (you can use a surrogate to get to a `struct` or `class` that *has* a `uint`, though).

Comment: I will try to explain. We have two kinds of protobuf stream sources:  embedded devices and SQL databases. Embedded devices using UInt32 format of DateTime (number of seconds from 1980.1.1), database using default protobuf-net format. I need one object to handle them both, so shim property doesn't work. Also we have a lot of protobuf structures with DateTime properties and it brings too many undesirable boilerplate code.

Comment: @GromHellscream can you clarify: on the embedded devices, is the property defined as `uint`? or as `DateTime`?

Comment: It defined as 'uint' on the embedded devices.

Comment: @GromHellscream without changes, the only way of mapping directly to `uint` would be via a shim property like shown above.

Comment: What changes are you talking about?

Comment: Any way to add serialization of custom structure to protobuf-net model?

Comment: @MarcGravell Is it somehow possible to enable surrogates for this case? Adding a shim property for every single `DateTime` is problematic.